# Dust will be the snake food..?

Tags: genesis, isaiah

Is there a connection between Gensesis 3:14 & Isaiah 65:25?? What does it means by dust in Genesis and Isaiah?

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermenetics. Please take our Tour to understand how we are different to other sites and what we expect from questions that show evidence of your own research.  Even copying and pasting the two Bible verses you mention would be helpful!  https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: This older question may be relevant: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/76263/why-does-the-serpent-continue-to-eat-dust-in-isaiah-6525?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the serpent continue to eat dust in Isaiah 65:25?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/76263/why-does-the-serpent-continue-to-eat-dust-in-isaiah-6525)

Comment: I initially voted to close this question as a duplicate but on second thought I think it should stand. @Mahlima for future reference it helps readers a lot if you include the passages in your question rather than simply  citing chapter and verse.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is "breath of life" in Genesis 2:7 is the same as spirit?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/2739/is-breath-of-life-in-genesis-27-is-the-same-as-spirit)

Answer (score 2):

> The wolf and the lamb shall pasture together,
> and the lion shall eat hay like the ox—
> but the serpent’s food shall be dust. None shall harm or destroy
> on all my holy mountain, says the Lord.

Yes, there is a connection here to Genesis, for it is highly unlikely that the prophet would not be aware that his dust-eating serpent also appears in Genesis.
Regarding the meanings of the two references:

**Eating dust in Genesis** means that the serpent, which formerly walked on all fours, now slithers on its belly. Culturally, it is a kind of origin story explaining why snakes do that, not a literal teaching that the snake would actually consume dust for nutrition. Theologically, it means that God brought the serpent low, interpreted in Christian theology to mean that Lucifer was cast down from heaven to earth or even lower.

**Eating dust in Isaiah** means that poisonous snakes will no longer threaten humankind or even other animals, just as lions will lie down with lambs etc. Some readers take this literally, others as symbolic of a peaceful world. But just as in Genesis, it is scientifically impossible that a snake could survive by eating dust, or that lions could live on hay. So those who take it literally would presume that God - who is all powerful - will miraculously change the animals' digestive system so that a lion's stomach works like that of a horse, and a snake's works like that of an earthworm.

Comment: A sort-of "lick the dust" idea? Brought as low as possible? Or is it deeper than that, given that man was made by God from the elements of the ground ('For dust thou art, and to dust thou will return'? Gen. 3:19) so that, having chosen to eat the food offered by the serpent, man discovers that serpent-food (dust) leads to death? I'm glad you changed your mind about closing this Q!